# No python interpreter in conda environment

Tags: anaconda, conda

Sometimes when I create a conda env, I get a folder that has no python interpreter in env//bin,

I was just curious about this behavior and why conda sometimes does this.

```
~/anaconda3/envs/pycuda$ ls
bin  conda-meta
$ cd bin/
~/anaconda3/envs/pycuda/bin$ ls
activate  conda  deactivate
```

This is make it difficult to configure the interpreter for pycharm.

Comment: What's "which python3" returning in these cases?

Comment: it's returning /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python3

Comment: How are you creating the environment? You have to specify Python as a dependency when you create the environment (unless you're installing another package that recursively depends on Python)

Comment: ah I see, so to create the environment I just use conda create -n "nameofenv", if you don't specify a python version